# Post disassociation requests should also apply to the author's messages in chat rooms generated from comments on the post

Tags: feature-request, status-review, chat, licensing, post-disassociation

A while ago I made a question, and later decided to be disassociated from that question. However doing so does not completely disassociate your account from this question.

If a comment thread gets migrated or continued in chat, these posts get moved and stay associated with your account, even if the question that spawned them is disassociated.

This seems like an oversight which needs resolved. From what I can tell, chat isn’t licensed any differently from questions, comments, and answers, so people could simply say, “hey, could you also remove my name from that chat room related to the question?” .

However, it seems to me like that is an unnecessary extra step that doesn't really need to be there. I cannot think of any case where it would be the intent of the user to remove their name from only some of the parts of the question.

As a result of this, it should be the default to disassociate related chat posts from a user when their question or answer is disassociated from their account. Would this be possible?

Comment: Please [edit] this question to clarify A) reconcile the title, which is worded as either a discussion or support question, with your use of the [tag:feature-request] tag. Are you asking for discussion? help/support? or actually proposing a change? B) Make it clear *exactly* what it is that you are saying should be removed from chat. Are you saying that you want your name removed from the actual messages of yours which were created from comments? something else? Saying just "remove my name from that chat room" doesn't make it clear what, exactly, you're wanting your name removed from.